# How to manipulate the DOM with Datatables and change the search box position

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've been reading the [official documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) and trying to understand how to change the location of the default search box with `DOM` manipulation but I couldn't make it work.

[LIVE DATATABLE DEMO](http://live.datatables.net/vepedopa/1/edit)

So basically what I want is to change the location of the search box and place it within the `<input title="Search"...` code keeping the same features.

I though this would do the trick, but it doesn't:

`"dom": '<"#search"f>'`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the search field with

```
dom: 'lrt'
```

and then you need to activate the search from your field with

```
// I have added id="search" to your search field to make it easier
$('#search').on('input', () =>
{
    DT1.search($('#search').val()).draw();
});
```

Here is the working fiddle

http://live.datatables.net/vepedopa/3/edit

Comment: Excellent and very easy to understand. Thank you!